# RO domain access

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to open RO access to specific group of domain users on linux server. Solution has to be universal i.e. work for new files, no necessity to constantly add/remove users etc
So far the best I can come up with is a script which checks the rights+S setgid.
Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use ACLs:

```
setfacl -R -m d:g:thegroup:rwx /your/dir
setfacl -R -m g:thegroup:rwx /your/dir
```

The first command sets the default ACLs (for new files) to `rwx` for `thegroup` recursively in `/your/dir`. The second command does the same for the currently existing files.

Comment: Problem is there are scripts which generate new data and it gets created with incorrect permissions. And if we make a script which fixes that we get delay and system load

Comment: @sergey, did you try it? The first line should take care of that, it sets default permissions that are used when new files are created.